# Build Path Exception using Spring 4.0.2 and eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have the same problem mentioned at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895981/eclipse-maven-spring-project-error). I have tried to find the solution every where but could not find one.

Here is information about my environment

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

IDE: eclipse kepler 4.3

Spring version 4.0.2

I have jdk 8 installed on my machine and I am using JRE 1.7 for the project

I do have aspectjweaver dependency in my POM file

```
      <dependency>
     <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

I can find the class BCException using `ctrl+shift+T`

Please find the screen shot of my eclipse.

[image: workspace]

[image: findResult]

Comment: In your screenshot maven directory structure not have like: `src/main/java` , `src/main/resources` , `src/main/webapp`. and see if solves by doing `mvn clean install`

Comment: add exception stack-trace to your question.

Comment: I do not have stack-trace and my application is running fine. Its the error coming from eclipse.